# Copy one element from an arralist and add it to another

Tags: java, arraylist

i have to take out a element from an arraylist, and move it to another.

I figured i could do that by copying the element from the first arraylist and add it to the other, and then delete it from the first arraylist, but i don't know how to make a copy of the element.

Comment: and you have tried what exactly? I don't see any code.

Comment: I just had to figure out the method to create a reference (even though it seems to be quite simple when looking at aaaahWhoosh answer), so what i had already tried don't really matter, since it was just trying to guessing how i could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have thought that removing from an ArrayList would be the hard part. Anyway, since this is Java, you can just create a reference to the object you are removing:

```
Object i = list1.get(indexYouWant);
list2.add(i);
```

Where 'Object' can be replaced with whatever the type of your object is. When you 'delete' the element from the first list, you will probably just be removing that list's reference to the element, rather than the element itself. Since the element is now referenced in the second list, it is safe from garbage collection and should live a perfectly happy life in the second list.

Comment: The first arraylist type is a super class of the second arraylist type. Is it possible to force the copy to be a type of the subclass?

Comment: You can use casting, as long as you know everything you're copying is always just a subclass hiding in a superclass. For instance, Subclass i = (Subclass) superclassObject;

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. And thanks to you, I can now leave comments on other people's posts!

Answer (score 0):

Implement `clone()` and, depending on your list elements' type, create a deep copy.

[A guide to object cloning in java](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/08/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/) will give you further instructions on cloning in Java.